# How can I select only one column using group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crud

I'm trying to select only **one** row from each portal (the last one by date) but I'm getting trouble with group by/distinct

Using this code, I can select only the portalId that I need, but without any data

```
Select relNews.PortalId
from news
left join relNews on relNews.NewsId= news.NewsId
group by relNews.PortalId
```

When I add one or more data columns like in this code, the select brings all the info, not only one for each portal

```
Select relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId
from news
left join relNews on relNews.NewsId= news.NewsId
group by relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId
```

I know that is a small trick that I'm missing here, but I just can't remember what...

### UPDATE

Lets make virtual tables for this example. The tables are `news` and `relNews` (I made them as short as possible here)

**Table news**

- NewsId
- Title
- Description
- Date

**Table relNews**

- RelNewsId
- NewsId
- PortalId

**NOTE:**

- relNews can have `N` registers of the same NewsId
- I need to select the last register for each portalId (based on news.Date).

Lets say:

**Table news**

- NewsId == 1
- Title == 'test'
- Description == 'test'
- Date == '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
- NewsId == 2
- Title == 'test2'
- Description == 'test2'
- Date == '2013-01-01 03:00:00'
- NewsId == 3
- Title == 'test3'
- Description == 'test3'
- Date == '2013-01-02 00:00:00'

**Table relNews**

- RelNewsId == 1
- NewsId == 1
- PortalId == 1
- RelNewsId == 2
- NewsId == 1
- PortalId == 2
- RelNewsId == 3
- NewsId == 2
- PortalId == 1
- RelNewsId == 4
- NewsId == 3
- PortalId == 3

This data should bring:

RelNewsId == **2**; RelNewsId  == **3**; RelNewsId == **4**;

---

I can get the result that I want with this code:

```
Select top 1 relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId, news.date
from news
left join relNews on relNews.NewsId= news.NewsId
where relNews.PortalId == 1
group by relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId
order by news.date desc
UNION
Select top 1 relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId, news.date
from news
left join relNews on relNews.NewsId= news.NewsId
where relNews.PortalId == 2
group by relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId
order by news.date desc
UNION
Select top 1 relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId, news.date
from news
left join relNews on relNews.NewsId= news.NewsId
where relNews.PortalId == 3
group by relNews.PortalId, news.NewsId
order by news.date desc
```

Then I get all 3 results.

Comment: What do you mean by "the select brings all the info"?

Comment: What DBMS & version please? MS SQL Server 2008? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain that. Let's say that with only one column I select 6 rows, but if I add the ID column I select 10 rows (example)

Comment: What is an "item"?  Your tables are called `news` and `relNews`.

Comment: @ErikE SQL Server 2008 going to put it in the question (sorry, used to Arqade, where the fewer the better for tags)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just Dummy names (I changed to be smallers) just it. item == row, going to edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide some way of indicating *which* one of the `news` rows you want, when there could be multiple for one `relNews` row. As you've discovered, the moment you `GROUP BY` a column that can have many values for each parent, then you get multiple rows. There are several ways to do this. Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you have several options.

1. **CROSS/OUTER APPLY** - change the `OUTER APPLY` to `CROSS APPLY` if you want to exclude `relNews` rows when there is no matching `News` row.

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      N.Whatever
   FROM
      dbo.relNews R
      OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT TOP 1 *
         FROM dbo.News N
         WHERE R.newsId = N.Id
         ORDER BY N.newsDate DESC
      ) N
   ```
2. **Row_Number()**

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      N.Whatever
   FROM
      dbo.RelNews R
      LEFT JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               *,
               Selector = Row_Number()
                  OVER (PARTITION BY N.Id ORDER BY N.newsDate DESC),
            FROM dbo.News N
         ) N ON R.newsId = N.Id
         AND N.Selector = 1
   ```
3. **Aggregate** - this is more complicated than it may seem to require, but I assumed that `newsDate` is NOT unique per `newsID`. If it *is* unique then it's simpler. This version works in SQL 2000. This is also probably the worst-performing query of all the options I am providing. Note that `UniqueColumn` is any column that has guaranteed unique values per `newsID` and can be used to select among ties for `newsDate`.

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      N.Whatever
   FROM
      dbo.RelNews R
      LEFT JOIN (
         dbo.News N
         INNER JOIN (
            SELECT N.Id, MaxUnique = Max(UniqueColumn)
            FROM
               dbo.News N
               INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT N.Id, MaxDate = Max(N.newsDate)
                  FROM dbo.News N
                  GROUP BY N.Id
               ) X ON N.Id = X.Id
               AND N.newsDate = X.MaxDate
            GROUP BY N.Id
         ) X ON N.Id = X.Id
         AND X.UniqueColumn = X.MaxUnique
      ) ON R.newsId = N.Id
   ```

   If `newsDate` is truly unique per `news.Id` then here is that query:

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      N.Whatever
   FROM
      dbo.RelNews R
      LEFT JOIN (
         dbo.News N
         INNER JOIN (
            SELECT N.Id, MaxDate = Max(N.newsDate)
            FROM dbo.News N
            GROUP BY N.Id
         ) X ON N.Id = X.Id
         AND N.newsDate = X.MaxDate
      ) ON R.newsId = N.Id
   ```
4. **Subquery** - with the problem that you can only pull one column at a time but works in SQL 2000, and should perform well with proper indexes. For multiple columns may perform badly as it may do a separate query for each one.

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      NWhatever = (
         SELECT TOP 1 N.Whatever
         FROM dbo.News N
         WHERE R.newsId = N.Id
         ORDER BY N.newsDate DESC
      )
   FROM
      dbo.relNews R
   ```
5. **Subquery in the ON clause** - probably the best query for SQL 2000 if you're going to pull multiple columns. Has to hit the News table twice, but with proper indexes it shouldn't be so bad. Note that `UniqueColumn` is any column that has guaranteed unique values per `newsID` and can be used to select among ties for `newsDate`.

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      N.Whatever
   FROM
      dbo.relNews R
      LEFT JOIN dbo.News N
         ON R.newsId = N.Id
            -- above condition not absolutely required logically,
            -- but definitely for indexes
         AND N.UniqueColumn = (
            SELECT TOP 1 N.UniqueColumn
            FROM dbo.News N
            WHERE R.newsId = N.Id
            ORDER BY N.newsDate DESC
         )
   ```
6. **Logical-Last** - another possibly good performer for SQL 2000. This is the same logical query as [fo_x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074852/57611) but expressed a little differently.

   ```
   SELECT
      R.Whatever,
      N.Whatever
   FROM
      dbo.relNews R
      LEFT JOIN dbo.News N
         ON R.newsId = N.Id
         AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.News X
            WHERE
               N.Id = X.Id
               AND (
                  N.newsDate < X.newsDate
                  OR (
                     N.newsDate = X.newsDate
                     AND N.UniqueColumn < X.UniqueColumn
                  )
               )
         )
   ```

Option #1 is probably the best for you in the database version you're using.

One last note: As always, **testing is required**. The performance of all these different queries will depend on a lot of factors: the pattern of your data (many dates for each news item or few), the exact indexes, how wide the tables are, and whether you add extra conditions (for example, the row number one as I suggested will not do so well if your conditions on the outer `relNews` table return only a few rows). If you find that one query is not providing satisfactory execution times, try a different one.

Comment: `Invalid column name 'newsDate'.` when I tested the select (Note, I changed to the right column name)

Comment: Which query # are you using from my list? Also, perhaps I am understanding your table structure backwards or something? Please provide names for the `newsDate` column and the `UniqueColumn` and indicate which table they are in. If my queries aren't working for you it's because I don't understand your structure well enough and need more info. Believe me: when you provide enough information we will be able to give the right query.

Comment: the third one (sorry forget to mention that)

Comment: I did find an error in that query a bit ago. Please recheck it. However, it is probably the worst-performing query I offered. Could you use another one?

Comment: Still testing them all. and uploading files and finishing small task at the same time... >.<

Comment: +1 Not tested all for the moment, but I learned one or two thing from your answer already =)

Comment: Note: I made a huge mistake. 1) I completely ignored `PortalId` somehow and 2) I assumed that the `relNews` table had only one row per `newsId`, and the `news` table had many rows per `Id`. I see now that I was probably totally wrong. Would you please update your question with more detail about your tables and their structure, with a few sample rows, so I can fix all my queries to work right?

Comment: sure, sorry for took so long to answer >.< Going to update it =)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a newsid is created sequentially and "news" is an "item", the following may be what you want:

```
Select relNews.PortalId, max(relnews.newsid) as MostRecentNews
from relNews
group by relNews.PortalId
```

You don't need the join if you just want the id.

Comment: I think it is unwise to rely on `newsid` being created sequentially. There are *always* times when data is entered late, or entered through the back-end, or corrected after the fact. Systems that rely on `identity` values to equate order-of-insertion with order-of-business-meaning are fragile and break (I say this from experience).

Comment: +1 good point, but in my case, I need more than just the ID. (I use only the ID in the question to make it small) @ErikE is right on the point of the data (an update for example, since the date is not the creation, but the exhibition one)

Comment: You have missing "INNER JOIN news" in your query

Comment: @AtheerMostafa . . . No, I left in the "on" clause accidentally.

Comment: @ErikE . . . That is why I explicitly say what my assumptions are before answering the question.

Comment: I wasn't critiquing your query per se--it is a great query if your given assumption is true. I was more trying to speak to the wider business, that it is *almost certainly never* a safe assumption. It makes logical sense when you take the "inside view", but when you take the "outside view" it is readily seen as risking fragility. Based on the experience I've had, I couldn't recommend a query relying on this assumption even if the OP said it was safe! But it's a great query for its purposes, thus why no -1. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have rank the portal-id by date

```
 select relNews.PortalId
 from news
 left join relNews on relNews.newsId = news.Id
 -- select rows for which there is no greater date than this row's date
 left outer join relNews2 on relNews.newsId = relNews2.newsId and relNews.date < relNews2.date
 where relNews2.PortalId is null
 group by relNews.PortalId, relNews.newsId
```

Comment: This query as written is not going to work, because the join to `relNews2` is not joining on `Id` and thus ONLY the most recent row in the `news` table (across the entire table) will be shown. Also, note that your query relies on `date` being distinct for each `news.Id` in the `news` table, which is not a safe assumption.

Comment: Ah thank you for catching both errors. I made an edit to the join condition to include `newsId`. You are absolutely correct about the uniqueness on `date`. I'd assumed distinct `date` since the question said "the last one by date".

Comment: I mean... there is no `relNews2` Table... o.O

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest and shortest way with highest performance too is using ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by ...) as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 20 News.*, 
ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by relNews.PortalId Order By news.Id DESC ) R
FROM news LEFT JOIN relNews on relNews.newsId = news.Id
ORDER BY R
```

I use top 20 here as these are the Portals count to show the first news in each Portal.

This is the best example to show and express the usage of "Partition By"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not what I need. I updated my question to try make it clear.